# Why a lot of ORM does not use pure python comparison in query?

Tags: python, django, orm, sqlalchemy, mongoengine

A lot of ORMs (like Django ORM or MongoEngine) use "keywords magic" like `id__lte=1` instead of more native `Model.id <= 1` (like in SQLAlchemy).

But why? It completely breaks down static analysis by IDE (refactoring, autocompletion and type checking).

Maybe there are some reasons that I can't see? Or just not so many people think that `Model.id <= 1` is better than `id__lte=1`?

---

Example for Django ORM:

```
Blog.objects.get(name="Cheddar Talk", user_reviews__lte=5)
```

Example for SQLAlchemy

```
session.query(Blog).filter(Blog.name == "Cheddar Talk", Blog.user_reviews <= 5)
```

Comment: By the way, some IDEs do understand Django syntax and assist with refactoring. I'm pretty sure you're right that it's harder (and hackier), but it's not impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem with "expression tree" magic like SQLAlchemy uses is that not all operators can be overloaded to capture the expression.

For example, you want `it <= 1` to be captured by `it` so it can be turned into a `WHERE it <= 1` expression in SQL? Pretty easy:

```
class Magic:
    def __le__(self, other):
        return MagicExpression(operator.le, self, other)
```

You build up a tree of those `MagicExpression` objects, and the code to turn that tree into a SQL query is pretty simple.

---

But what if you also want to capture `it in other_query` and turn that into a SQL `IN` or `BETWEEN` expression? That doesn't work. For one thing, the `__contains__` gets called on the other thing, not your magic thing. And, worse, whatever `__contains__` returns gets converted to `bool` by the interpreter. So, if you try this:

```
class Magic:
    def __contains__(self, other):
        return MagicExpression(operator.contains, other, self)
```

… and then try `it in it2`, you're going to get `True` (or whatever `MagicExpression.__bool__` returns), which isn't something you can convert into a SQL `IN` or `BETWEEN` later.

And what if you try to `and` two conditions together? Well, you can't even overload the `and` operator. If the left `MagicExpression` is falsey, you'll just get that; otherwise, you'll get the right one.

Also, of course, there's the simple problem that sometimes you want a static test that doesn't even use any of the magic things, at least for debugging purposes. "OK, something is wrong in my test on that column… what if I just test against 0 and see what the query returns?" But you can't turn `count > 0` into a `MagicExpression` if `count` and `0` are both plain Python integers.

---

Some people think these limitations are acceptable. Maybe you can design things to use `&` and `|` in place of `and` and `or`, and make people write the "uglier" version instead of `in`, and so on. So a lot of queries end up simple, but some end up a hybrid of simple and ugly—still better than all of them being ugly, right? The problem is that it can be a bit of a bug magnet—it's very easy to forget the limitations and use an `and` or an `in`, and end up with an expression that looks right but doesn't do what you wanted.

So, other people think that isn't acceptable, and just require you to do everything the "ugly" way so there's no temptation to write hard-to-debug broken queries.

And of course some people build a LINQ-esque DSL on top of list comprehensions and use import hooks to translate that into valid SQL-building or ORM-using Python.

Comment: I don't use "ugly" syntax. But you are right that some people can mistakenly think that `and`/`or`/`in` also works.

Comment: @ADR If you prefer SQLAlchemy, of course use SQLAlchemy. You may also want to check out some of the various libs for doing LINQ-style queries or LINQ-esque extended comprehensions. The alchemy version is nice, but `[(blog.name, blog.posts) for blog in session.query if blog.name == "Cheddar Talk" and blog.user_reviews <= 5 order by blog.name]` is pretty cool too.